# Client crashes at startup in Dynamics AX 2012 R2

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I just change the datasource  of my form, when I tried to save the form the client crashed.

Ever since the client crashed every time i tried to start it up

Does anyone else have this problem? Or does anyone have an explanation or solution?

Error log:

```
Name of the corrupted application: Ax32.exe, version: 6.3.6000.10707, timestamp: 0x5fd6ef55
Name of the corrupted module: Ax32.exe, version: 6.3.6000.10707, timestamp: 0x5fd6ef55
Exception Code: 0xc00000fd
Error offset: 0x0001dbe0
ID of the faulty process: 0x4a1c
Start time of the faulty application: 0x01d7f183a25b6a92
Path of the faulty application: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics 
AX\60\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe
Path of the corrupted module: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics 
AX\60\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe
Berichtskennung: dfd93a82-3ef5-43f0-92a3-e893babff96e
Full name of the corrupted package: 
Application ID relative to the corrupted package:
```

Comment: With the client closed, go to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local` (aka `%localappdata%`), and delete all of the `*.auc` and `*.kti` files. Then go to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Dynamics Ax` and delete everything in that folder. Then try and reopen the AX client. If that doesn't work, try another AX client on a different machine. If that does work, then reinstall your AX client. If that doesn't work, you have another issue.

Comment: thanks after deleting  and recompiling  it now  work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the client closed, go to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local` (aka `%localappdata%`), and delete all of the `*.auc` and `*.kti` files. Then go to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Dynamics Ax` and delete everything in that folder.

Then try and reopen the AX client. If that doesn't work, try another AX client on a different machine. If that does work, then reinstall your AX client. If that doesn't work, you have another issue.